# How to convert rows to columns from database results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a Ruby project that is backed by Postgres. I have a table that has a date field called `first_ship_date`, and a delivery status which is a Rails enum.

I need to create a hash or array that looks something similar to the following:

```
[ { week: 2016-01-04,
    0: 15,
    1: 30,
    2: 8
  },
  { week: 2016-01-11,
    0: 8,
    1: 45,
    2: 37
  }
]
```

Once this is complete I will be displaying the result in a Google Chart.

Here is what I have so far:

```
SalesOrder.order("date_trunc('week', first_ship_date) ASC")
  .where("delivery_status is not null")
  .where("date(first_ship_date) >= ? AND date(first_ship_date) <=?", Date.new(2016,1,1), Date.new(2016,3,31))
  .pluck("date_trunc('week', first_ship_date)", :delivery_status)
```

This returns an array with values similar to:

```
[ [2016-01-04 00:00:00 UTC, 0],
  [2016-01-04 00:00:00 UTC, 2],
  [2016-01-04 00:00:00 UTC, 2],
  [2016-01-04 00:00:00 UTC, 2],
  [2016-01-04 00:00:00 UTC, 2] ]
```

What is the best and most efficient method to convert this raw data to the hash/array above, keeping in mind the value of the enum isn't always visible? Meaning, for some weeks we don't have all of the delivery_status values.

Comment: You should do this in your database query with `group` and `count`, not in Ruby after the fact.

Comment: As @Jordan said, do it in the database. It's designed for these sort of things, and by doing it there it reduces the load on your network and Rails host, which is a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

**ANSWER**

Using `Enumerable#inject`: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject

One-liner:

```
your_array_or_arobject.inject({}) {|h,y| h[week = y[0].to_date.to_s] ||= []; h[week] << y[1]; h}.inject({}) {|h,(k,v)| h[k] = {week: k}.merge(v.each_with_index.inject({}) {|h,(k,i)| h[i] = k; h}); h}.values
#=> [{:week=>"2016-01-04", 0=>15, 1=>30, 2=>8}, {:week=>"2016-01-11", 0=>8, 1=>45, 2=>37}]
```

Multiline:

```
hash = your_array_or_arobject.inject({}) do |h,y| 
  h[week = y[0].to_date.to_s] ||= []
  h[week] << y[1]
  h
end

hash2 = hash.inject({}) do |h,(k,v)| 
  h[k] = {week: k}.merge(
    v.each_with_index.inject({}) do |h2,(k,i)| 
      h2[i] = k
      h2
    end
  )
  h
end

hash2.values
#=> [{:week=>"2016-01-04", 0=>15, 1=>30, 2=>8}, {:week=>"2016-01-11", 0=>8, 1=>45, 2=>37}]
```

---

**PROOF**

Via console:

```
irb(main):159:0> x = [
irb(main):160:1*   ["2016-01-04 00:00:00 UTC", 15],
irb(main):161:1*   ["2016-01-04 00:00:00 UTC", 30],
irb(main):162:1*   ["2016-01-04 00:00:00 UTC", 8],
irb(main):163:1* 
irb(main):164:1*   ["2016-01-11 00:00:00 UTC", 8],
irb(main):165:1*   ["2016-01-11 00:00:00 UTC", 45],
irb(main):166:1*   ["2016-01-11 00:00:00 UTC", 37]
irb(main):167:1> ]
=> [["2016-01-04 00:00:00 UTC", 15], ["2016-01-04 00:00:00 UTC", 30], ["2016-01-04 00:00:00 UTC", 8], ["2016-01-11 00:00:00 UTC", 8], ["2016-01-11 00:00:00 UTC", 45], ["2016-01-11 00:00:00 UTC", 37]]
irb(main):168:0> x.map! {|y| [DateTime.parse(y[0]), y[1]]}
=> [[Mon, 04 Jan 2016 00:00:00 +0000, 15], [Mon, 04 Jan 2016 00:00:00 +0000, 30], [Mon, 04 Jan 2016 00:00:00 +0000, 8], [Mon, 11 Jan 2016 00:00:00 +0000, 8], [Mon, 11 Jan 2016 00:00:00 +0000, 45], [Mon, 11 Jan 2016 00:00:00 +0000, 37]]
irb(main):169:0> hash = x.inject({}) {|h,y| h[week = y[0].to_date.to_s] ||= []; h[week]  {"2016-01-04"=>[15, 30, 8], "2016-01-11"=>[8, 45, 37]}
irb(main):170:0> hash.inject({}) {|h,(k,v)| h[k] = {week: k}.merge(v.each_with_index.inject({}) {|h,(k,i)| h[i] = k; h}); h}.values
=> [{:week=>"2016-01-04", 0=>15, 1=>30, 2=>8}, {:week=>"2016-01-11", 0=>8, 1=>45, 2=>37}]
```

---

**UPDATE**

Refactored for count of occurrences for each value.

One-liner:

```
your_array_or_arobject.inject({}) {|h,y| h[week = y[0].to_date.to_s] ||= []; h[week] << y[1]; h}.inject({}) {|h1,(k,v)| h1[k] = {week: k}.merge(v.inject({}) {|h2,k| h2[k] ||= 0; h2[k] += 1; h2}); h1}.values
```

Multiline:

```
hash = your_array_or_arobject.inject({}) do |h,y|
  h[week = y[0].to_date.to_s] ||= []
  h[week] << y[1]
  h
end

hash2 = hash.inject({}) do |h1,(k,v)| 
  h1[k] = {week: k}.merge(
    v.inject({}) do |h2,k| 
      h2[k] ||= 0
      h2[k] += 1
      h2
    end
  ) 
  h1
end

hash2.values
```

---

**PROOF**

Via console:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'date'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> x = [
irb(main):003:1*   ['2016-01-04 00:00:00 UTC', 0], 
irb(main):004:1*   ['2016-01-04 00:00:00 UTC', 2],
irb(main):005:1*   ['2016-01-04 00:00:00 UTC', 2],
irb(main):006:1*   ['2016-01-04 00:00:00 UTC', 2],
irb(main):007:1*   ['2016-01-04 00:00:00 UTC', 2],
irb(main):008:1*   ['2016-01-04 00:00:00 UTC', 2],
irb(main):009:1*   ['2016-01-04 00:00:00 UTC', 0],
irb(main):010:1*   ['2016-01-04 00:00:00 UTC', 2],
irb(main):011:1*   ['2016-01-04 00:00:00 UTC', 0],
irb(main):012:1*   ['2016-01-04 00:00:00 UTC', 2],
irb(main):013:1*   ['2016-01-04 00:00:00 UTC', 2],
irb(main):014:1*   ['2016-01-04 00:00:00 UTC', 2],
irb(main):015:1*   ['2016-01-04 00:00:00 UTC', 2],
irb(main):016:1*   ['2016-01-04 00:00:00 UTC', 2],
irb(main):017:1*   ['2016-01-04 00:00:00 UTC', 2]
irb(main):018:1> ]
=> [["2016-01-04 00:00:00 UTC", 0], ["2016-01-04 00:00:00 UTC", 2], ["2016-01-04 00:00:00 UTC", 2], ["2016-01-04 00:00:00 UTC", 2], ["2016-01-04 00:00:00 UTC", 2], ["2016-01-04 00:00:00 UTC", 2], ["2016-01-04 00:00:00 UTC", 0], ["2016-01-04 00:00:00 UTC", 2], ["2016-01-04 00:00:00 UTC", 0], ["2016-01-04 00:00:00 UTC", 2], ["2016-01-04 00:00:00 UTC", 2], ["2016-01-04 00:00:00 UTC", 2], ["2016-01-04 00:00:00 UTC", 2], ["2016-01-04 00:00:00 UTC", 2], ["2016-01-04 00:00:00 UTC", 2]]
irb(main):019:0> x.map! {|y| [DateTime.parse(y[0]), y[1]]}
=> [[#<DateTime: 2016-01-04T00:00:00+00:00 ((2457392j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, 0], [#<DateTime: 2016-01-04T00:00:00+00:00 ((2457392j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, 2], [#<DateTime: 2016-01-04T00:00:00+00:00 ((2457392j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, 2], [#<DateTime: 2016-01-04T00:00:00+00:00 ((2457392j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, 2], [#<DateTime: 2016-01-04T00:00:00+00:00 ((2457392j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, 2], [#<DateTime: 2016-01-04T00:00:00+00:00 ((2457392j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, 2], [#<DateTime: 2016-01-04T00:00:00+00:00 ((2457392j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, 0], [#<DateTime: 2016-01-04T00:00:00+00:00 ((2457392j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, 2], [#<DateTime: 2016-01-04T00:00:00+00:00 ((2457392j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, 0], [#<DateTime: 2016-01-04T00:00:00+00:00 ((2457392j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, 2], [#<DateTime: 2016-01-04T00:00:00+00:00 ((2457392j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, 2], [#<DateTime: 2016-01-04T00:00:00+00:00 ((2457392j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, 2], [#<DateTime: 2016-01-04T00:00:00+00:00 ((2457392j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, 2], [#<DateTime: 2016-01-04T00:00:00+00:00 ((2457392j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, 2], [#<DateTime: 2016-01-04T00:00:00+00:00 ((2457392j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, 2]]
irb(main):020:0> x.inject({}) {|h,y| h[week = y[0].to_date.to_s] ||= []; h[week] << y[1]; h}.inject({}) {|h1,(k,v)| h1[k] = {week: k}.merge(v.inject({}) {|h2,k| h2[k] ||= 0; h2[k] += 1; h2}); h1}.values
=> [{:week=>"2016-01-04", 0=>3, 2=>12}]
```

Comment: Here is an exact listing of my beginning array:

`[[2016-01-04 00:00:00 UTC, 0], [2016-01-04 00:00:00 UTC, 2], [2016-01-04 00:00:00 UTC, 2], [2016-01-04 00:00:00 UTC, 2], [2016-01-04 00:00:00 UTC, 2], [2016-01-04 00:00:00 UTC, 2], [2016-01-04 00:00:00 UTC, 0], [2016-01-04 00:00:00 UTC, 2], [2016-01-04 00:00:00 UTC, 0], [2016-01-04 00:00:00 UTC, 2], [2016-01-04 00:00:00 UTC, 2], [2016-01-04 00:00:00 UTC, 2], [2016-01-04 00:00:00 UTC, 2], [2016-01-04 00:00:00 UTC, 2], [2016-01-04 00:00:00 UTC, 2]]`

Comment: when I run this code against my array i get ...

`"2016-01-04"=>{:week=>"2016-01-04", 0=>0, 1=>2, 2=>2, 3=>2, 4=>2, 5=>2, 6=>0, 7=>2, 8=>0, 9=>2, 10=>2, 11=>2, 12=>2, 13=>2, 14=>2, 15=>2, 16=>2, 17=>2, 18=>2, 19=>2, 20=>2, 21=>2, 22=>2, 23=>2, 24=>2, 25=>2, 26=>1, 27=>2, 28=>1, 29=>2, 30=>1, 31=>1, 32=>2, 33=>2, 34=>2, 35=>2, 36=>2, 37=>1, 38=>2, 39=>2, 40=>2, 41=>2, 42=>2, 43=>2, 44=>2, 45=>2, 46=>2, 47=>1, 48=>2, 49=>0, 50=>2, 51=>1, 52=>2, 53=>2, 54=>0, 55=>2, 56=>2, 57=>2, 58=>2, 59=>2, 60=>2, 61=>1, 62=>2, 63=>2, 64=>2,`

Comment: ^^ your solution doesn't use the same starting data

Comment: Without a database to query, my starting data used strings, which were converted to `DateTime` class with `DateTime.parse(y[0])`—same functionality after.

Comment: To clarify, you want **unique values** in your result? Currently, the result against your beginning array is **each occurrence**, right?

Comment: Ok. I think you want the **count of occurrences for each value**. I'm updating my answer now.